# How to change background-image url('') in runtime?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

At runtime I will know the client phone's network and so on, but how can I change the `background-image` css property?

Because of the compatibility，I cannot use the service worker to intercept the request.

Media queries are not suitable because there are too many options.

**Can I use css vars or calc to solve this problem?**

```
:root {
    --post-fix: '@q_80'

    --url:'http://imgdoc.bce.baidu.com/bce-documentation/BOS/image.jpg'var(--post-fix)
}
```

Comment: Please, format your question.

Comment: No, you can't concatenate strings with css variables, what you can do though is to edit this url variable altogether from js (note that it would have to include the `url(` part as well) , or even just set a class from js and different values according to each class.